# IIS redirect to error page without windows authentication prompt

Tags: web, iis-7.5

We are using a portal site for a bunch of our applications. We're using windows authentication to login to the portal. But if a user might be locked in AD they will get a 401 back from IIS. 
In that scenario i want to redirect them instantly to my custom errorpage.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="401Error.html" responseMode="File" />        
    </httpErrors>
```

I want to redirect them instantly without the windows authentication login prompt showing.
[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeaQn.png

This is what i want to avoid, that page should show what so ever and just redirect to error page instantly. Only after you click cancel it gets redirected to the error page..

Ive tested alot of things in IIS and webconfig and im running out of ideas. Since this is only IIS, our code never gets reached.